# Bytecode manipulation on Android class

Tags: android, bytecode, javassist

I would like to do bytecode manipulation on android.view.View class (adding methods), is it possible? Should I use javassist or maybe a different library?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve that is not in the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.
Android uses its own bytecode format which is not compatible to the "standard" bytecode format javassist and other libs operate on.

http://bravenewgeek.com/dalvik-bytecode-generation/

Comment: by using dexmaker I could add methods to Android class?

Comment: According to https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/issues/4 you can't change existing classes, but you can create new Subclasses. Not sure if this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This article outlines a technique of manipulating the bytecode (using javassist, but asm et. al. will do it too). The catch is that the manipulation is done at build time while the classes are still in Java bytecode.http://brianattwell.com/using-bytecode-manipulation-to-further-kill-android-boilerplate/